# visual studio 2013 GIT ignore list doesn't ignore dlls

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, gitignore

I am using **Visual Studio Online** GIT repository on Visual Studio 2013, for some reason my project bin, obj directories and other Dlls and Pdbs are not ignored in change tracking.

Here is my .gitignore file, I tried all suggestions found online, like adding .tfignore and other stuff, nothing really helped.

```
# Download this file using PowerShell v3 under Windows with the following comand
# Invoke-WebRequest https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kmorcinek/2710267/raw/ -OutFile .gitignore

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.sln.docstates

# Build results

[Dd]ebug/
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/

# Enable "build/" folder in the NuGet Packages folder since NuGet packages use it for MSBuild targets
!packages/*/build/

# MSTest test Results
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*/
[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*

*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ilk
*.meta
*.obj
*.pch
*.dll
*.pdb
*.pgc
*.pgd
*.rsp
*.sbr
*.tlb
*.tli
*.tlh
*.tmp
*.tmp_proj
*.log
*.vspscc
*.vssscc
.builds
*.pidb
*.log
*.scc

# OS generated files #
.DS_Store*
ehthumbs.db
Icon?
Thumbs.db

# Visual C++ cache files
ipch/
*.aps
*.ncb
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.cachefile

# Visual Studio profiler
*.psess
*.vsp
*.vspx

# Guidance Automation Toolkit
*.gpState

# ReSharper is a .NET coding add-in
_ReSharper*/
*.[Rr]e[Ss]harper

# TeamCity is a build add-in
_TeamCity*

# DotCover is a Code Coverage Tool
*.dotCover

# NCrunch
*.ncrunch*
.*crunch*.local.xml

# Installshield output folder
[Ee]xpress/

# DocProject is a documentation generator add-in
DocProject/buildhelp/
DocProject/Help/*.HxT
DocProject/Help/*.HxC
DocProject/Help/*.hhc
DocProject/Help/*.hhk
DocProject/Help/*.hhp
DocProject/Help/Html2
DocProject/Help/html

# Click-Once directory
publish/

# Publish Web Output
*.Publish.xml

# NuGet Packages Directory
## TODO: If you have NuGet Package Restore enabled, uncomment the next line
#packages/

# Windows Azure Build Output
csx
*.build.csdef

# Windows Store app package directory
AppPackages/

# Others
sql/
*.Cache
ClientBin/
[Ss]tyle[Cc]op.*
~$*
*~
*.dbmdl
*.[Pp]ublish.xml
*.pfx
*.publishsettings
modulesbin/
tempbin/

# EPiServer Site file (VPP)
AppData/

# RIA/Silverlight projects
Generated_Code/

# Backup & report files from converting an old project file to a newer
# Visual Studio version. Backup files are not needed, because we have git ;-)
_UpgradeReport_Files/
Backup*/
UpgradeLog*.XML
UpgradeLog*.htm

# vim
*.txt~
*.swp
*.swo

# svn
.svn

# SQL Server files
**/App_Data/*.mdf
**/App_Data/*.ldf
**/App_Data/*.sdf


#LightSwitch generated files
GeneratedArtifacts/
_Pvt_Extensions/
ModelManifest.xml

# =========================
# Windows detritus
# =========================

# Windows image file caches
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db

# Folder config file
Desktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Mac desktop service store files
.DS_Store

# SASS Compiler cache
.sass-cache

# Visual Studio 2014 CTP
**/*.sln.ide
*.dll
*.pdb
```

This last section in the ignore list, helped to ignore dlls and pdbs in untracked changes, but not in included changes and excluded changes

```
 # Visual Studio 2014 CTP
    **/*.sln.ide
    *.dll
    *.pdb
```

Comment: Did you already check them in?  `.gitignore` applies only to new files that are not in the repository.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Yea. I happen to check them in once. How would I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **/ to the dll directories, since that searches for them in any folder (not just the root directory):

**/*.dll 
**/*.pdb

Remove your current files with "git rm file" (or "git rm -rf folder" to remove the whole bin folders).

Comment: i tried to run this in GIT Bash "git rm -rf OneProjectFolderName/bin" it gave a error fatal: pathspec 'OneProjectFolderName/bin' did not match any files

Comment: Already updated gist https://gist.github.com/kmorcinek/2710267 to ignore nuget packages.